# Bayesian networks implementation in Java

Tags: java, conditional-statements, probability, intersection, bayesian

Bayesian network: Please am currently doing a project on bayesian networks in java and am stuck on how to calculate p(a|b) because from a questionnaire, i only have the values of p(a), p(b). Please anyone with experience in this field can help me out. websites that i checked required that i have the value of p(anb). How do i calculate p(anb) in this case since the probabilities if a, b were calculated from a questionnaire Please anybody help me out and i have to calculate this p(a|b) for several variables. I would really appreciate if anyone helps me out. Thanks

Comment: Did you try writing code? If yes, please post here along with the problem that you're facing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_formula this is all you need to know. The rest comes from you.

Answer (score 1):

Bayes' theorem states that the probability of A given B, P(A|B), is equal to the probability of both A and B occurring, P(A∩B), divided by the probability that B occurs, P(B).
That is,
p(A|B) = P(A∩B) / P(B)

Now, P(A∩B) is equal to the probability of B given A, P(B|A), times the probability of A, P(A).
That is,
P(A∩B) = P(B|A) x P(A)
In your experiments, P(B|A) should already be known from your sample. That is, of the total population of A, how many samples correspond to B.

This would give the final formula,
p(A|B) = [P(B|A) x P(A)] / P(B)

Comment: thank you for your contribution. I'll try this out. I'm grateful to all who took time to answer me